# Solr/Lucene: What is the difference between regular queries and filter queries

Tags: lucene, solr

I'm currently implementing a Solr solution where a user is able to select various options to search for a product. I can now take all those options and put them together into one single long query, or I can use a query that fetches everything (*:*) and applies query filters to it.

Regular query:

```
q=color:blue AND price:500
```

Query using filter queries:

```
q=*:*&fq=color:blue&fq=price:500
```

The result is exactly the same. So what is the difference? When should I use one or the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Filter queries do not influence scores of the document.
Further they are useful in Caching, the queries specified with fq are cached independently from the main query
[Document for solr query parameters](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters)

Answer (score 0):

Typically in any production system you would use a variant of the `Dismax` request handler which doesn't support the former syntax, hence filtering must be performed using *filter queries* in that case.